# Create a table and fill Cells with Python

Tags: python

I want to create a table with python and fill it in this way:

I have my data like this: (X,Y,Value)

The X-values are the header of my columns.

The Y-values are the header of my rows.

```
   |     X_1      |       X_2      | ...
   | ------------ | -------------- |
```

| Y_1 ||    Val_1     |      Val_3     | ...
| Y_2 ||    Val_2     |      Val_4     | ...
...       ...              ...

For every (X,Y) i have to write some Value.

All my data are lists. The output file can be an Excel-Worksheet or a csv-file.

What's the best way to create this table step by step ? Is it possible with pandas-dataframes ?

Comment: What exactly is the input? Please give an example

Comment: Header columns is (X_1, X_2, X_3 ...) and i have them in a list.
Header rows is (Y_1, Y_2, Y_3 ...) and i have them in a list.
For every (X, Y) i have a value which has to be in the corresponding cell. I have the values in a list too.

Comment: So you have a list of X's, a list of Y's and a list of Values?

Comment: @Anynamer Yes, that's right.

Comment: Are the Values in a list of lists, i.e. a matrix? Or one long list?

Comment: They're a one long list.

Comment: Okay, so does the long value list iterate one row at a time? So that Values[1] is the value for X[1],Y[0] ?

Comment: Yes, it's like that.

Comment: Cool, with that input value setup my answer below should work:)

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to generate a dataframe like you say in the question. You can generate a dataframe from a python dictionary like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'x_1': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'x_2': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'value': [10,20,30,40]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)
```

Then convert it to csv using: `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')`

This will save the dataframe as csv. Make sure the format of your output is right by adjusting the dictionary.

Comment: i meant that for every couple of (X,Y) i have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming there are values for all x, y cordinates, this could be a straight forward method: first make a numpy array with dimensions of X and Y, then make into pandas dataframe and add columns and indeces from X and Y, then save as csv.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# make numpy array of values
n, d = len(X), len(Y)
np_vals = np.reshape(np.array(Values), (n, d)))

# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np_vals, columns = X, index = Y)

#save as csv
df.to_csv('your_file.csv', sep = ',')
```

you can also use df.to_excel if desired.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution with 3 Lists having the same length but i got this error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 21 into shape (21,21)
Am i missing sth ?

Comment: If the 3 lists X, Y, and Values are the same length, then you don't have values for all x,y cordinates. The length of your values list should be len(X)*len(Y) according to your description?